# From HTML to CSS style with Python

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I've extracted certain elements from a HTML page with beautifulsoup and want to extract the according CSS styles (which reside in most cases in external css files) via python.

How can i get a jQuery selector if I have a HTML element? If i had this selector, i could use cssutils to parse the CSS and get it.

TIA for help.

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with it?

Comment: You can target CSS content parsed by cssutils via these selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [PyQuery's API](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/api.html). It provides similar css selector syntax as jQuery does and it's much faster than beautifulsoup because it relies on lxml to do the parsing work.

```
import pyquery.PyQuery as pq # you can treat it as a css selector

html = '<div class="foo"><a href="somewhere"></a></div>'
parsed = pq(html) # PyQuery object, is a callable

pq_list = parsed('.foo a') # doing css selection
for node in pq_list: # node here is a lxml element object
    print node.attrib['href'] # => somewhere
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried pyquery but it doesnt solve my problem:
I need to generate a selector from an HTML-element to query the CSS file. Do you see a way doing this?

Comment: @Josh Maybe you could manually do it by iteratively calling `node.getparent()` and retrive tagname, id and classnames for each node.